# I need a Excel formula to find the coordinates of the point in the new bent cylinder.

Tags: parameter-estimation

In the beginning, I have a straight cylinder where I have the value of the distance of plane 2 from the beginning of the cylinder and an angle value of the point on the surface.

Then, I will have a coordinate table of the interceptions of the lines that form the new bent cylinder with the corresponding radius values.

Therefore, with the distance and angle value of the straight cylinder, I need an Excel formula to find the coordinates of the point in the new bent cylinder.
x=320.6559801
y=156.2865235
z=-34.49968948
radius=40

Could you provide support with parametric equations?
I need to make a formula in Excel so that when I change the coordinates of the point before the bend I can find the new coordinates after the bends.
This is the input data...so you will need to work from this is be the input data...so you will need to work from this.

Comment: We cannot see what you can see. You need to provide a picture.